# How to change color of navigation for scrolling on the site?

Tags: css, colors, scroll, navigation, transition

I'm auditioning for a new website, using Wordpress. Shifted the primary navigation above the header image, and let the transparent color. 
After spending the navigation monitor window with the contents of the site, I want it to change to black. To better understand the test site is this: http://new.blogchampz.com/

How do I do that? I know that includes CSS and JS ...

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to track the scroll position. Once the header hides from the viewport, then you must add an additional class for the header menu with a background color of black.

CSS:

```
.darkMenu {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var headerHeight = HEIGHT OF HEADER;
    if($(document).scrollTop() > headerHeight){
        $('MENU SELECTOR').addClass('darkMenu');
    }
    else{
        $('MENU SELECTOR').removeClass('darkMenu');
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Add the following css in your stylesheet,

CSS:

```
.masthead-fixed .site-header {
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little layman. In wordpress, do you know which document I insert the JS? 
Previously did the same procedure in "custom-header" and did not work.

Comment: Include a separate JS file for all your custom scripts, include it in the footer of your theme.

Comment: I did not. Could you explain step by step?

Comment: Check the updated answer. This worked when i used chrome inspect tool to apply this style in your site.